# I want to create a IP's ping test script

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to check (ping) a list of IP addresses from a text file and need to be notified when any IP is unreachable from that lis. Could anyone can help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need. You could also tweak it to output to a file, or email output to you etc... It reads IP addresses from file ip-list.txt

Let me know if you need any explanation.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
        if ping -c 1 $line
        then
                echo "$line OK"
        else
                echo "$line DOWN"
        fi
done <ip-list.txt

exit
```